# Android In-app Billing Version 3 - ITEM NOT OWNED

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm facing an issue with IAB V3, while purchasing the item, interrupt the network(or airplane mode immediately.
after re-buy the item it said "you already owned this item"
I tried many things: clear Google Play cache/force close Google Play/Force close the game/restart the devcie/switch to another device/wait for some days, non-of them work.
I went through internet with Google but no similiar cases... Most of them are solved by clear cache or not call consume...

Sometimes, Google Play say "Item Already Owned"

Sometimes, when query the inventory I saw that item, but when I tried to consume it, it returned error 8: ITEM NOT OWNED.(response: 8:Item not owned)

This is really suck and I cannot buy that item again unless use another account.

The issue is really hard to reproduce but once it's happen, you cannot do anything...

I have no clue how to debug the next step.
I think it maybe belong to Google lib itself.
Note: My lib code is pretty same as TrivialDrive app.

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Is there anyone have solution on this? I'm stuck with this issue nearly one week now...

Comment: hello, Is there any solution?

Comment: any solution for this? I am also running into this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Response error : 7 and response error: 8 "Item already owned" and "Item already purchased" occurs from Google play service. Once the purchase flow is finished we need to consume as the following method.

`mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS),  mConsumeFinishedListener);`

But if you already purchased and if you have this issue you need to clear the Google play services cache data and then test it using consume Async

Comment: I always tried to call consumeAsync the item when the item available in inventory.
But the thing is sometimes it's not available, sometimes it's available but when call consume, Google return error 8: ITEM not OWNED.
So thing still same...

Tried to clear Google Play services cached also not work for me.